# Search & Paging using Repeater control

Tags: asp.net

Anyone give me a example about Search & Paging using Repeater control.
tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are for *pagging*:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article456-custom-seo-friendly-paging-with-aspnet-repeater-or-datalist-control-.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Aspnet_Repeater_Control.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345